# Program for watching log files with ruby ​​on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, logging, development-environment, ruby-debug

Do you know a good program for mac OS. For clear and easy viewing logs in your ruby on rails application.

I know I can be in the terminal

```
tail-f log / development.log
```

or

```
less + F-R log / development.log
```

Anyone knows a program not on the ...
mysql logs are the most important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rubymine has a dedicated server log console when you run your app from within Rubymine.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a whole mess of them at [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Log_Analysis).